# Subfolders are created in all resourceTypes in CkFinder

Tags: javascript, php, ckfinder

Using CkFinder V3 in file config.php have setup different resourceTypes.

The settings works and I get in CkFinder on the left panel two "entries" called "My Images" and "My Videos".

Now when I select folder "My Videos" and create a sub folder, the sub folder is being added on "My Videos" and also on "My Images".

I need to add a sub folder only in the place where user decided too.

What is wrong in my configurations?

```
$config['resourceTypes'][] = array(
    'name'              => 'Images',
    'label'             => 'My Images',
    'maxSize'           => '2M',
    'allowedExtensions' => 'gif,jpeg,jpg,png',
    'deniedExtensions'  => '',
    'backend'           => 'default'
);

$config['resourceTypes'][] = array(
    'name'              => 'Videos',
    'label'             => 'My Videos',
    'maxSize'           => '1G',
    'allowedExtensions' => 'mp4',
    'deniedExtensions'  => '',
    'backend'           => 'default'
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both resource types you have defined point to the same folder (the root folder of the `default` backend), because they do not define a `directory`. To use separate folders please use the `directory` option, like presented below:

```
$config['resourceTypes'][] = array(
    'name'              => 'Images',
    'label'             => 'My Images',
    'maxSize'           => '2M',
    'allowedExtensions' => 'gif,jpeg,jpg,png',
    'deniedExtensions'  => '',
    'directory'         => 'images', // ←
    'backend'           => 'default'
);

$config['resourceTypes'][] = array(
    'name'              => 'Videos',
    'label'             => 'My Videos',
    'maxSize'           => '1G',
    'allowedExtensions' => 'mp4',
    'deniedExtensions'  => '',
    'directory'         => 'videos', // ←
    'backend'           => 'default'
);
```